# PySimpleGUI Crashing when using "print()" and "sg.cprint()"

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI to make a program that calls functions from another file directory. I am trying to make a multiline output as a part of my program using sg.cprint() and every time I try to run the program multiple times it crashes and gives me this:

"Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00000002032be2c0 (most recent call first)"

Before this I was having each function just print to the terminal. But when I tried to do this it started to crash on me.

Currently I have all of my sg.cprints() and print() commands commented out and the program runs as expected. But when they are uncommented it starts to crash again.

Comment: It maybe happened when you have two libraries, one is PySimpleGUI, try to control the `stdout`/`stderr` at the same time. No body can tell you what's wrong in your code because you say nothing about it.

Comment: "every time I try to run the program multiple times it crashes and gives me this" - implies you are using an IDE? Can you explain what this means?  If you launch from a command line (not an IDE) do you have the problem?